# Java WebService with .NET issue.  Results different with scvutil /wrapped and not

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010, soap

I'm using a well known vendor's [API](https://portal.ultradns.com/static/docs/NUS_API_XML_SOAP.pdf) with a WSDL [link1](http://ultra-api.ultradns.com:8008/UltraDNS_WS/v01?wsdl), [link2](http://uploading.com/files/8e767a6c/UltraDNS.xml/) (click `wait to download`):

The above mentioned documentation wants me to create an Authentication request packet like this:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=‖http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/‖
xmlns:web=‖http://UltraWebServiceLocation/‖>
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=‖1‖ xmlns:wsse=‖http://docs.oasisopen.
org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd‖>
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=‖UsernameToken-16318950‖ xmlns:wsu=‖http://docs.oasisopen.
org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd‖>
<wsse:Username>bwooster</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type=‖http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-
token-profile-1.0#PasswordText‖>**********</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>QTvkiqEFK7uJuOssMndagA==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2009-04-14T21:20:57.108Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

My client binding looks like this; and am using a service reference instead of a web reference.

```
        UltraDNS.UltraDNS1Client client = new UltraDNS.UltraDNS1Client();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";

        var results = client.getResourceRecordsOfZone("domain.com",1);
        // Throws InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'UltraWSException'.
        // Detail:
        //{"Namespace='http://webservice.api.ultra.neustar.com/v01/' is not supported with rpc\\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified."}
```

The web config looks like this

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="UltraDNS1Binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://ultra-api.ultradns.com:80/UltraDNS_WS/v01"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UltraDNS1Binding"
                contract="UltraDNSService.UltraDNS1" name="UltraWebServiceV01Port" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

When I use SVCUtil to generate the proxy class with the `/wrap` parameter I get the following error:

```
{"The top XML element 'result' from namespace '' references distinct types System.String and ZoneInfoData[]. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have used "Add Web Reference". Please use "Add Service Reference" instead.

Then see [Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx).

---

The service is sending you a fault of some kind (UltraWSException). WCF is having trouble deserializing it, but if you turn on message tracing, you may be able to see what the error is, and fix it.

Comment: I attempted that but am getting errors about SOAP/Literal being enabled.  I changed the setting on all classes and methods in the generated reference but no luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I took a coffee break to get a fresh perspective... updated the question.